# Can not add user to Facebook custom audience via marketing api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am creating a web site that allow to connect ads account, create custom audience and add list of users to created custom audience.
My site work well when i connect my Facebook developer account. 
But when i try to connect a other account (not developer or admin), 
i can connect ads account, create a new custom audience from my site but can't add users to created custom audience (Ads Management Basic Access permission is approved)
What did i miss ? And what should i do ?

```
ERROR doAction 49 exception 'FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException' with message '(#2650) service error' in /var/www/html/brandco/apps/vendor/facebook/php-ads-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Http/Exception/RequestException.php:137
```

Comment: If this keeps happening please file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/ and we'll take a look. Make sure to include as much detail as possible: your App ID, your URLs, the error you receive, screenshots etc.